# Split and Add Space Between Phone Number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to format a telephone number into a neater format that adds a space between every third and seventh character from the front.

```js
var string = "02076861111"
var phone = [string.slice(0, 3), " ", string.slice(3)].join('');
console.log(phone);
```

Where do I place the method for the seventh character so `020 7686 1111` is returned?

Comment: Well if you did it for 3, why not do the same thing over again for 7? except this time, the 7th position becomes the 8th because of the space.

Comment: Would that require a third variable, or can I do that in the `phone` var?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In a single replace :

```
var string = "02076861111"
var phone = string.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d{4})/, '$1 $2 $3');
console.log(phone);
```

Of course, that assume you always have a perfect string (no space, hyphen or other characters, 10 character...)

A more strict regexp could be like this :

```
var phone = string.replace(/\D*(\d{3})\D*(\d{4})\D*(\d{4})\D*/, '$1 $2 $3');
```

But still, that wouldn't catch every possibilities.

Comment: `var str = "02076861111"; str.replace(/^\s*([0-9]{3})\s*\-?([0-9]{3})\s*\-?([0-9]{4})$/, '$1 $2 $3');` will take care of possible whitespace and hyphens.

Comment: Is there any benefit to using `.replace` over `.slice`? Very new to this all, and trying to find and understand why this is the more elegant solution.

Comment: @realph actually, there is no advantage of using regexp, it is slower. But with regexp, it is easier to control the validation than with slice.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon So am I right in thinking that `.replace` method splits the string into three chunks of 3, 4 and 4 and then prints them as `$1 $2 $3` with spaces?

Comment: @realph you are half right, replace take the matching string and replace it with the second argument. `$1` is what matched in the first parenthesis, `$2` the second and so on!

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Ok I understand. What does the `(\d)` mean?

Comment: @realph `\d` mean digit only while `\D` mean not digit character.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative solution:

```js
function numberWithSpaces(value, pattern) {
  var i = 0,
    phone = value.toString();
  return pattern.replace(/#/g, _ => phone[i++]);
}

console.log(numberWithSpaces('02076861111', '### #### ####'));
```

Answer (score 4):

Just slice it again:

```js
var string = "02076861111";
var phone = [string.slice(0, 3), " ", string.slice(3,7), " ", string.slice(7)].join('');

console.log(phone);
```

Slice takes a start and (exclusive) end index. Note, if the end index is missing, it'll take the rest of the string.

So the first slice takes index 0 thru 2, the second takes index 3 thru 6 and the last slice takes index 7 to the end of the string.

Comment: Just to "reduce" the code, you could do `[string.slice(0, 3), string.slice(3,7), string.slice(7)].join(' ');`

Answer (score 2):

Why use slice, when a regular expression can work

```js
console.log( "02076861111".replace(/(\d{3})\D?(\d{4})\D?(\d{4})/,"$1 $2 $3") );
```

and this will not blow up if the user enters in spaces to start.

Comment: Good answer, for a *better* validation, you could use `[\s-\.]*` (and other chars). Or yeah `\D*` like in your edit.

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider that only numbers with 11, 12 and 13 characters are valid, you have to know that a valid phone number consists of the country code plus 10 digits. therefore I wanted to format phone numbers by country code, and then some arbitrary groups, like +1 555 555 5555, +22 555 555 555, or +333 555 555 5555.

therefore I wanted a function that filters digits and formats them:

```js
export const formatPhone = (phone: string) => {
  const myPhone = phone.match(/(\d)/g)?.join(``);
  if (myPhone === undefined) return ``;
  if (myPhone?.length === 11) {
    return myPhone.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, `+$1 $2 $3 $4`);
  }
  if (myPhone?.length === 12) {
    return myPhone.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, `+$1 $2 $3 $4`);
  }
  if (myPhone?.length === 13) {
    return myPhone.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, `+$1 $2 $3 $4`);
  }
    
  return myPhone;
};
```

if you want a function to validate a number it would be something like this

```js
export const validatePhone = (myPhone: string) => {
  if (myPhone === ``) return ``;

  const phone = myPhone.match(/(\d)/g)?.join(``);

  if (phone === undefined) return `only numbers are valid`;

  if (phone?.length > 13 || phone?.length < 11)
    return `${phone} is not a valid number`;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log( "02076861111".replace(/^\d{3}-\d{8}$/) );
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work.