# How to apply space in value of <input type="number">?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to add space in `<input type="number">` value in html.

But whenever i add space in value like this `value="0401 889 889"` than there is nothing appear in `<input type="number">`.

**Without adding a blank space**

If i am not add blank space in `<input type="number">`'s value than its works fine.

[image]

```
<input type="number" value="0401889889">
```

**After adding a blank space in ``**

[image]

```
<input type="number" value="0401 889 889">
```

**What i exactly want**

[image]

```html
<h2>Without adding a space in value</h2>
<input type="number" value="0401889889">

<h2>With adding a space in value</h2>
<input type="number" value="0401 889 889">
```

Comment: `type="number"` does not allow spaces, you have to use `type="text"` and then use something like regex to validate and allow the pattern you desire. something like `pattern="[0-9 ]+"`

Comment: try value="0401&nbsp;889&nbsp;889"

Comment: @alakmarShafin That will not work since, since `type="number"` only allows numbers

Comment: You might also want to check the ['tel' input type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel)

Comment: why aren't you using <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}"> because chousing type="number" for taking mobile number as an input is not good practice, type="number" is only used for smaller values (e.g. 1,2,3) . 

Answer (score 1):

Instead, you can use this

```html
<input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}">
```

Comment: But it's allow to type characters

Comment: @JigneshPanchal that depends on whether the browser supports the "tel" input type or not; if it does not, it falls back to a "text" input type therefore it will accept anything. If you want to prevent users from typing alphabetic characters you need to set an event listener for the "change" event that validates/modify the input value on-the-fly.

Comment: CORRECTION: you should listen for the "input" event, not the "change" one

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent users from typing alphabetic characters you need to set an event listener for the "input" event that delete invalid characters from the value on-the-fly:

```js
const phone = document.getElementById('phone');
phone.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  // delete any character that is not a digit or a space
  event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/[^0-9^ ]/gi, '');
});

// or, if you have more than one input of type "tel" (e.g. mobile and landline)

const phones = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=tel]');

phones.forEach(phone => phone.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/[^0-9^ ]/gi, '');
}))
```

```html
<input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="0401 889 889" pattern="[0-9]{4} [0-9]{3} [0-9]{3}">
<input type="tel" id="mobile" name="mobile" placeholder="0401 998 998" pattern="[0-9]{4} [0-9]{3} [0-9]{3}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/25121813/14050736

You'll have to modify the regex a bit according to the group of number you desire

Edit : I just noticed : Your input must be in "text" not "number"